# Submitting data via POST - the server responded with a status of 400

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch, react-final-form

My task is to send the data from the form via POST request as a JSON to the page. I've tried with `fetch` and `axios` and had the same response in console.

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2),
  };

  fetch("https://frosty-wood-6558.getsandbox.com/dishes", requestOptions)
    .then((res) => res.json());
};
```

In console I get:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()". What's wrong?

Comment: have tried using postman.if so could you post params you sent and other detail

Comment: I have to do it in React without postman.